# How to implement dependent drop down (multiple select) in Zend Framework 1.12 using AJAX and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I have to implement a search feature where dependent drop downs are used. I have one parent dropdown which shows the level 1 select items with multiple select, based on multiple selection on parent dropdown the first child dropdown should be populated from database.

The items on this first child dropdown can also be multiple selected. Based on multiple selection of first child dropdown the second child drop down should be populated and items on second child dropdown can also be multiple selected.

I have been able to populate the drop downs only for single select. But I want multiple selection on all dropdowns and populate accordingly. If there is any other methods or forms that could replace this mechanism is also welcomed.

Comment: Would you edit into your question the relevant pieces of code that you have? It seems to me that you'd just want to (a) work out what items you have selected in a menu, (b) send them to the server via AJAX when they change, and (c) redraw your child menus. I expect changing menu 1 would redraw menu 2 with nothing selected, so you do not have to recompute what was already selected in all your descendants (i.e. menu 3 can be removed until the user chooses something from its parent again).

Answer (score 2):

You maybe looking for [jQuery cascading dropdown](http://www.dnasir.com/github/jquery-cascading-dropdown/demo.html)

It will fetch values from database (in JSON format) for a child select element options every time a parent value is selected. 
You may have to create a JSON returning controller, which should have following code for returning JSON

```
$this->_helper->json($req_data);
```

Also, obviously, create a function in your required DAO for fetching data based on the parameters.

Given example in the Dynamic dropdown section show similar code that you can use.

```
$('#example2').cascadingDropdown({
selectBoxes: [
    {
        selector: '.step1',
        source: [
            { label: '4.0"', value: 4 },
            { label: '4.3"', value: 4.3 },
            { label: '4.7"', value: 4.7 },
            { label: '5.0"', value: 5 }
        ]
    },
    {
        selector: '.step2',
        requires: ['.step1'],
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('/api/resolutions', request, function(data) {
                var selectOnlyOption = data.length <= 1;
                response($.map(data, function(item, index) {
                    return {
                        label: item + 'p',
                        value: item,
                        selected: selectOnlyOption // Select if only option
                    };
                }));
            });
        }
    },
  .. and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem after doing some study and exploring javascript.

First:
I defined the select form on Zend as

```
$form['selectform1'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('selectform1');
            $form['selectform1']->addMultiOption('', 'Select Expertise');
                foreach ($selectform1options as $selectform1value) {    
                    $form['selectform1']->addMultiOption($selectform1value['id'], $selectform1value['selectform1ooptions']);
                }
            $form['selectform1']->setLabel('Label for select form 1:')->setRequired(); 


            $form['selectform2'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('selectform2');
            $form['selectform2']->setLabel('Select form 2:')                                        
                                ->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
            $form['selectform2']->addMultiOption('', 'Please select options on select form 1 first');

            $form['selectform3'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('selectform3');
            $form['selectform3']->setLabel('Selectform 2:')
                                            ->setAttrib('disabled', 'true')                                            
                                            ->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);                                            
            $form['selectform3']->addMultiOption('', 'Please select options for select form 2 first');
```

Second:
I used javascript as follows.

```
$("#selectform2").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#selectform2").hide();
$("#selectform2-label").hide();
$("#selectform3").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#selectform3").hide();
$("#selectform3-label").hide();

$("select[id='selectform1']").click(function() {
    $("#selectform2").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#selectform2").hide();
    $("#selectform2-label").hide();
    $("#selectform3").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#selectform3").hide();
    $("#selectform3-label").hide();
    $("select[id='selectform1']").change(function() {
        $("#selectform3").empty();
    });
    var selection_selectform1 = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/function1',
        data: {
            id: selection_selectform1
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#selectform2").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#selectform2").show();
            $("#selectform2-label").show();
            $("#selectform2").html(response);
        }
    });
});

$("select[id='selectform2']").click(function() {
    $("#selectform3").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#selectform3").hide();
    $("#selectform3-label").hide();
    var selection_selectform2 = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/function2',
        data: {
            id: selection_selectform2
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.trim() == 'empty') {
                $("#selectform3").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("#selectform3").hide();
                $("#selectform3-label").hide();
            } else {
                $("#selectform3").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#selectform3").show();
                $("#selectform3-label").show();
                $("#selectform3").html(response);
            };
        }
    });
});
```